# Wildfly - MDB stops processing other messages after error occur in one message

Tags: jms, wildfly, message-queue, activemq-artemis, message-driven-bean

To simplify the problem I've configured an MDB with only one session.

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenContext;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/queue/adwordsReportRequest"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue = "veiculo = 'adwords'"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transactionTimeout", propertyValue = "7500") })

public class ReportRequestReceiveDispatcherAdwords implements MessageListener {

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext mdc;

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    private Integer count = 0;

    public ReportRequestReceiveDispatcherAdwords() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
        TextMessage msg = null;
        String text = null;
        try {
            if (inMessage instanceof TextMessage) {

                msg = (TextMessage) inMessage;
                text = msg.getText();

                if (count >= 10 && count <= 100) {
                    logger.error("Count: {} - {} -  Marcando como erro!", ++count, text);
                    throw new RuntimeException("teste de erro");
                } else
                    logger.info("Count: {} - {}", ++count, text);

            } else {
                logger.warn("Message of wrong type: " + inMessage.getClass().getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            mdc.setRollbackOnly();
        }

    }

}
```

The Queue is configured with 3 attempts and 2 minutes of delay between them.

```
 <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-delivery-attempts="3" redelivery-delay="120000" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
```

Executing this code with 600 messages in the queue:

```
14:10 --> it stopped the processing at the first error.
14:12 --> processes 3 messages and stops.
14:14 --> processes 10 messages and stops.
14:16 --> processes 14 messages and stops.
14:18 --> processes 10 messages and stops.
14:20 --> processes 16 messages and stops.
14:22 --> processes 9 messages and stops.
14:24 --> processes 8 messages and stops.
14:26 --> processes 7 messages and stops.
14:28 --> processes 6 messages and stops.
14:30 --> processes 6 messages and stops.
14:32 --> processes 6 messages and stops.
14:34 --> It goes out of the loop that generates error, so it finish the processing of the other messages until the queue is empty.
```

Why the MDB stops if still there is messages in the queue? When a message comes back to the queue after a rollback, it goes to the top blocking te rest? It's not making any sense to me. I couldn't find any doc where this behavior is described.

According to the specification:

> Other subsequent messages will be delivery regularly, only the
>   cancelled message will be sent asynchronously back to the queue after
>   the delay.
>   https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.0.0/undelivered-messages.html

Comment: which app server?

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot to say. It's Wildfly.

Comment: I think this is expected because you are rolling back that complete transaction `mdc.setRollbackOnly();`, what was your expectation with `mdc.setRollbackOnly();`, did you try not rolling back using `mdc.setRollbackOnly();`?

Comment: If I don't use mdc.setRollbackOnly() it won't be retried, it will be commited.

Comment: @Camilla You can set the transaction with auto commit as FALSE. Firstly, did you try to skip that see if you get remaining messages in the queue?

Comment: @hagrawal, Thank you for your help but I'm not sure if I understood. With the rollback, I get remaining messages in the queue as expected. I want them to keep there. The problem is I just want those that generated errors  to be processed after the ones that haven't been tried yet.

Comment: See if this helps -  http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/jboss-jms-queue-example or http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/connecting-to-an-external-wildfly-jms-server